# React-Bootstrap Tooltip requires overlay error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am just using `Tooltip`, and not an `OverlayTrigger`, but I am getting the error:

> webpack-internal:///133:33 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `overlay` is marked as required in `Tooltip`, but its value is `undefined`.

The code is:

```
 <Tooltip title="tooltip-for-node" placement="right" className="in" id="tooltip-right"
              positionTop={this.state.tooltipY} positionLeft={this.state.tooltipX}>
              Tooltip right
            </Tooltip>
```

As you can see I tried setting the `title` as is suggested in the thread:

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6897

It did not help. According to the official documentation `Tooltip` does not have `overlay` property required:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/

So, I am confused and not sure what I can try further to make it work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was pretty non-informative. I noticed that I forgot to import `React-Bootstrap`s' tooltip and the script was using a different `rc-tooltip`:

```
import Tooltip from 'rc-tooltip';
```

After fixing the imports it started to work well:

```
import {Tooltip as BTooltip} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Tooltip from 'rc-tooltip';
```